# a little issue in responsive queries?

Tags: html, css

hi all i have a little problem here i have some divs that i have positioned in below screen width

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1399px) {
  .logo{margin-top:70px;}
  .menu_bt{display:block; margin-left:30px;}
  .search_bt{display:block; margin-left:30px;}
}
```

so i above u can see i have positioned some divs and i have shown some hidden divs and they are looking fine on above screen width but when i change browser width to 768px it doesn't show the styles i have set in 1024px screen width for e.g(.menu_bt and .search_bt) i have changed them from display:none to display:block but they doesn't show up in 786px screen width.i have to set those above properties in below mentioned screen width to get them ....i dont know whats the issue please help me out

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .logo{margin-top:70px;}
  .menu_bt{display:block; margin-left:30px;}
  .search_bt{display:block; margin-left:30px;}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code in your media queries? You're showing duplicate code blocks...

Comment: `min-width: 1024px` means use this rule is screen is 1024px or wider. The rules will not trigger on narrower screens. So what exactly is the issue?